# Does psychology/cognition come prior to mathematics?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

I am not a hundred percent sure this belongs in Philosophy SE, but I couldn't think of a better SE to ask it, so I am asking it here. I got into an argument with a friend who claimed that the science of psychology/cognition (I am using the terms "psychology" and "cognition" interchangeably) comes prior to mathematics. He claimed this because we use cognition to discover mathematical truths. I disagreed with him. I claimed that, while we do use cognition to discover mathematics, the truths of mathematics exist timelessly and they were true even before there were humans or other sentient beings around. So, then, my question is, does cognition come prior to mathematics? I believe that mathematics comes prior to even the laws of physics, not just cognition, but I would love to hear a good argument challenging my view.

Comment: epistemically or ontically?

Comment: There seems to be no disagreement between you, you just use "prior" in different senses. Truths of mathematics existing before there were humans is perfectly compatible with humans using cognition to discover them. When the latter is pushed further to say that mathematical truths thereby *depend* on psychology that would be called *psychologism*. One traditional argument against it is that mathematical laws are far more precise and general than anything psychological. See [SEP, Psychologism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/psychologism/) for more.

Comment: One way to challenge your Platonism view of math ontically is to bear in mind mathematics is just knowledge like any other field of specialized knowledge, which is philosophically defined as justified true belief. So at the end of the day math is essentially a perhaps extremely firm belief, but still just a human belief which may be subjected to belief suspension such as the case LEM rejected by intuitionists. It's even speculated as in Lurianic Kabbalah the whole truth is of infinite nature while lower-level worlds (natural numbers as perceived) are finite thus finitism with numbers is false

Comment: It's like you see two apples but an alien only sees a field with continuous variations, never having a concept of a whole natural number (remember no two exact objects).Another attack can be from Berkelian like idealism, even if there's an ontic Platonic realm of math forms, it has nothing to do with beings equipped with a mind. All the application of math to applied fields are entirely dependent on the agents who carry out such applications to the physical world and everyone's own math contents are different in different nonstandard minds which cannot be simply classified as a few categories.

Comment: A dog can catch a ball without understanding mathematics. Maths is discovered, it's true, but it's a language and as such describes things which existed before without description.